# Hyper-V: Guest has no route to host with external netowrking

Tags: linux, networking, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V setup where there are some services running on the host along side the VMs which the VMs themselves need to access.The VMs network is setup as an external network, bridged with the host's physical NIC.

The VM in question is an Ubuntu Linux machine. It successfully get an IP address on the network via DHCP, resolves DNS with the networks DNS server, resolve the host's DNS and can access the internet, however it has no network to the host itself.

I can't see any firewall rules, nor any options pertaining to host access in the Virtual Switch options, nor can I find anything useful on the internet.

Ideally the services on the Host would be running on a VM as well and could be part of the same network but that isn't possibly right now.

Does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Microsoft explicitly doesn't want you to be running services on the Hyper-V host.  Anyway, you probably need to tell us more about what specific services, and how you have your Hyper-V networking setup.

Comment: I do understand that isn't the ideal setup here. I would change it if I could. 

I'm afraid I don't really know much about Hyper-V to comment specifically but as far as I know it's a more or less Out of the box setup, nothing special, on Windows 10. The guests are running docker containers that run Jenkins nodes. The issue is that some of the jobs that are run on the node requires an internal DNS resolution by hostname to the VM host.

There are no guest firewall rules, and no related active deny rules on the windows host either.

Comment: I do have a feeling it's a Hyper-V network stack issue. Why would you want a guess to access the host ever? Sounds like a security nightmare, but it's where I'm at.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to configure "[Internal](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/)" [vSwitch](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/07/24/private-vs-internal-virtual-switches.aspx) for your Ubuntu VM as additional network and use this network for your applications. However, as @Zoredache mentioned in comment, if you will give us more details about the networking setup and share "ip-tables" from ubuntu it would be great!